# Iterating through a string in Python in 8-character chunks

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I have very long binary numbers stored in strings. Each 8 characters (i.e. each 8-bit chunk) represent an ASCII character code. To give an example, 0100100001101001 is 2 8-bit numbers (01001000 & 01101001), which are the character codes for 'H' & 'i'. So the whole thing is a binary representation of 'Hi'.

My question is, is there a way to force a for loop iterate through a string in bigger chunks so that I can read 8 letters at a time? In other words, I'd like the for loop to assign 8 characters to my iterator variable per loop iteration instead of 1, so that I can easily determine the character codes represented by the string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a duplicate: this one is about strings, the other one is about "general" kinds of lists. `textwrap` will probably only work on strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just throwing this answer in, perhaps not the most appropriate way to do things, but you *can* use `textwrap`:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> s = '0100100001101001'
>>> textwrap.wrap(s, 8)
['01001000', '01101001']
```

Comment: That's a decent solution. Taking it one step further, after reading about that function, the code:

`code` b=textwrap.wrap(s, 8) `code`

creates a new list that is easily iterable. Thanks

Comment: It made me wait a couple minutes before I could accept it :)

Comment: I am missing a warning here about things that the function does without the user possibly aware of: `expand_tabs`, `replace_whitespace`, etc.